# Routes configuration in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to know the difference between them.

```
get "public/show"
get "public#show"
get "show/:something", :to => "public#show"
```

Thanks,
Mezbah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) public/show
Since you do not specify a controller or action, Rails uses it's convention to map the URL "public/show" to the show action of the PublicController.

2) public#show

This is not a valid route.

3) show/:something

You define a parameter called "something" in the URL.  This means that a URL such as "show/dog" and "show/cat" will call the show action of the PublicController.  You can get the parameter as a string ("cat" or "dog) by using params[:something] in the controller.

The Rails documentation is really good.  A good source of more information on routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html